# How set flipper key value in routing from rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Application has two RecordsController in different namespace. I need store old logic get records endpoint while developing new endpoint in new controller. Old Rspec tests with disabled flipper key  should calling old route.

I would like to add flipper key to routing.rb file like this

```
if $flipper[:get_records_api].enabled?
          resources :records, only: %i(show create update destroy)
        else
          resources :records, only: %i(index show create update destroy)


scope module: "objects" do
          if $flipper[:get_records_api].enabled?
            resources :records, only: %i(index)
          end
        end
```

Rspec test set flipper value like this `describe "index records", get_records_api: false:`

The issue is the tests calling new endpoint. In rspec tests flipper is false. How I understand the routing is initialized when rails app starting and in this moment flipper is true.

Comment: You can instead try adding the flipper logic as a before callback in the controller/s.